# Face detection code doesnt work

Tags: face-detection

I am currently trying to find the face in a particular image.I am following
 this website :
 http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_2/index.html.
 I am following the code in this page.But i dont seem to see the option/part
 of the code to include my image[ am i supposed to change the argv[1] part in the code to my own image inorder to read my image]

Can someone guide me?
 Or is there any better face detection code available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to pass your picture as a command line argument.